# Viscous Burgers equation physical meaning

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity, non-linear-systems, integrable-systems

The viscous [Burgers' equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation):
$$ q_{t}+q\:q_{x}~=~\nu\:q_{xx}, \mbox{ where } \:\:\nu >0, $$
combines the nonlinear propagation of $q(x,t)$ and the diffusion.

- What is this equation for? (in modelling context)
- What is so special about it? (other than if $\nu=0$ then the solution can form a shockwave)

Answer (score 6):

1D Burger's equation is not meant to model a physical phenomenon. Rather, it is a simplification of homogeneous incompressible Navier-Stokes equations that preserves (some of) its mathematical structure: the non-linear convection term and the second order derivative of viscous forces.

It was initially intended as a useful simplification to try to understand the mathematical problems present in N-S equations, e.g. the limit of small viscosities (high Reynolds number). It is not anymore a tool for researchers studying existence and uniqueness of solutions of N-S equations, but is still useful to test numerical schemes designed for N-S.

Its multidimensional version also arises in some other physical contexts, see http://arxiv.org/abs/nlin/0012033

Comment: *but it's still useful to test numerical schemes* pretty much how Randy LeVeque treats it. Also useful for instructing someone on discretion methods of hydrodynamic, which is related to your comment.

Comment: I think it also provides one of the ways the Reynolds number is derived, or at least physically demonstrated.  For the form shown in the OP, R = $\frac{ q \ q_{x} }{ \nu \ q_{xx} }$, which shows that the Reynolds number can represent the ratio of steepening to viscosity (or in KdV equations, viscosity is replaced by dispersion).

Answer (score 1):

The [convection-advection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation) equation resembles the mathematical structure of Burgers equation. Despite differences (convection-advection has an "extra" variable $c(x,t)$) you can think that Burgers describes compressible material fluid transportation by means of advection (the $ \vec{v} \cdot \nabla $ term) and diffusion (the $D \nabla^2$ term) without mechanical pressure gradients applied.